# What does functional_qml_application_uses_friends mean?

Tags: application-development

In a review for my click package, I saw the following message:

```
functional_qml_application_uses_friends
```

What does it mean and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

The Friends API is being dropped from the supported frameworks, and friends-service will also be dropped from the framework definition for 14.10.
The friends-service on the phone will be available as long as the 14.04 framework is supported, but it will not be allowed by the SDK when targeting 14.10.